# I am trying to get the key of a particular word from a Word2Vec Vocabulary

Tags: python, dictionary, nlp, word2vec, gensim

### Word2Vec

Currently I am trying to perform text classification on a text corpus. In order to do so, I have decided to perform `word2vec` with the help of `gensim`. In order to do so, I have the code below:

```
sentences = MySentences("./corpus_samples") # a memory-friendly iterator
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences, size=100, window=5, min_count=5, workers=4)
```

My sentences is basically a class that handles the File *I/O*

```
class MySentences(object):
    def __init__(self, dirname):
        self.dirname = dirname

    def __iter__(self):
        for fname in os.listdir(self.dirname):
            for line in open(os.path.join(self.dirname, fname)):
                yield line.split()
```

Now we can get the vocabulary of the model that has been created through these lines:

```
print(model.wv.vocab)
```

The output of which is below(sample):

```
t at 0x106f19438>, 'raining.': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab object at 0x106f19470>, 'fly': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab object at 0x106f194a8>, 'rain.': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab object at 0x106f194e0>, 'So…': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab object at 0x106f19518>, 'Ohhh,': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab object at 0x106f19550>, 'weird.': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab object at 0x106f19588>}
```

As of now, the dictionary that is the vocabulary, contains the word string and a `<gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab object at 0x106f19588>` object or such. I want to be able to query an index of a particular word. In order to make my training data like:

```
w91874 w2300 w6 w25363 w6332 w11 w767 w297441 w12480 w256 w23270 w13482 w22236 w259 w11 w26959 w25 w1613 w25363 w111 __label__4531492575592394249
w17314 w5521 w7729 w767 w10147 w111 __label__1315009618498473661
w305 w6651 w3974 w1005 w54 w109 w110 w3974 w29 w25 w1513 w3645 w6 w111 __label__-400525901828896492
w30877 w72 w11 w2828 w141417 w77033 w10147 w111 __label__4970306416006110305
w3332 w1107 w4809 w1009 w327 w84792 w6 w922 w11 w2182 w79887 w1099 w111 __label__-3645735357732416904
w471 w14752 w1637 w12348 w72 w31330 w930 w11569 w863 w25 w1439 w72 w111 __label__-5932391056759866388
w8081 w5324 w91048 w875 w13449 w1733 w111 __label__3812457715228923422
```

Where the `wxxxx` represents the index of the word within the vocabulary and the label represents the class.

---

### Corpora

Some of the solutions that I have been experimenting with, is the `corpora` utility of `gensim`:

```
corpora = gensim.corpora.dictionary.Dictionary(sentences, prune_at=2000000)
print(corpora)
print(getKey(corpora,'am'))
```

This gives me a nice dictionary of the words, but this corpora vocabulary is not the same as the one created by the `word2vec` function mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:**

`model.wv.vocab['my_word'].index`

where `'my_word'` is the word whose index you want (Eg. `'hello'`, `'the'`, etc).

**Long Story:**

This is so because gensim stores the `Vocab` object in the `model.wv.vocab` dictionary.

That is the reason you get results like`'raining.': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab object at 0x106f19470>` when you try to print the dict.

The `Vocab` object is initialized with the index like so:

`wv.vocab[word] = Vocab(count=v, index=len(wv.index2word))`

and thus allows access to this property.

I don't understand why you would need to represent it so, but this should do the trick.

More details can be found in their [source](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/word2vec.py)